# Div centering what is the best option

Tags: html, css, centering

What is the best way to center a div with a absolute position div in it and no fixed height?

This is what i'm making:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBHDL.png

**Option1:**

```
.holder{width: 100%; float: left;}
.content{margin: 0 auto; width: 1200px; position: relative;}
.dropdownmenu{position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;}
```

This gives a scrollbar to "holder" and needs a overflow visible. but the height wil be automaticly 0 and "content" can't have paddings.

**Option2:**

```
.holder{width: 100%; float: left; text-align: center;}
.content{display: inline-block; text-align: left; position: relative;}
.dropdownmenu{position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;}
```

This seems to be the best solution but I don't know if its "allowed", and it seems kinda hacky

**Option3:**

```
.holder{width: 100%; float: left; position: relative;}
.content{margin-left: -600px; left: 50%; width: 1200px; position: absolute;}
.dropdownmenu{position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;}
```

This seems to work great but its not that "responsive" and i need to fix a lot to make it good responsive.

**Option4:**

The translate-x option... but thats not supported enough.

The problem is that I want to center a div and stil can use position absolute without the overflow (scrollbars) problem. And stil have a automatic height with paddings.

Comment: Option 2 looks good to me

Comment: If #2 works the best for you, you should roll with that! :-)

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: @Paulie_D The programming issue is explained at the end of my post:

The problem is that I want to center a div and stil can use position absolute without the overflow (scrollbars) problem. And stil have a automatic height with paddings.

But I will go on and use a **display: inline-block;**. thanks for the confirmation xdevs23 and Cobra_Fast

Comment: **Edit:** Display: inline-block;  gives weird margins on position fixed/absolute elements. So i'm going to use display flex to center my divs... and just **** IE9 etc